# Copy over sheet1

Tags: excel, excel-2007

In Excel 2007:
I want to copy over values in SHEET2 so that it is identical to Sheet1
I am doing it with:

```
=(SHEET1!B1)
```

This has the side effect of copying a 0 instead of an empty cell. (or a date 01-01-1900)

How can I copy over the SHEET1 Values while ignoring empty cells?

An example of what I want to see:

```
SHEET1
A1|B1|
  | 3|

SHEET2
A1|B1|
  | 3|

Not
A1|B1|
 0| 3|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions for you.

**Formula:**

`=IF(Sheet1!A1 = ""; ""; Sheet1!A1)`

---

**Macro:**

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a question i got asked by someone. They just let me know that the first solution worked for them.